# nested arrays spacing

Tags: math-mode, arrays

I'm trying to align two child arrays to a parent array. At the moment my code gives:

[image]

Which means, the two child arrays refer only to first row and fourth row of parent array. I would like the curly braces to be centered at row 2 and in the middle of row4 and row5, possibly being aligned with the respective parent rows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\qquad\textbf{b)}\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_1+a_{13}x_3+a_{14}x_{4}=b_1
\left\{
{
\begin{array}{l}
a_{11}z_1+a_{12}z_2+a_{13}z_3=r_1\\
a_{22}z_2=r_2\\
a_{31}x_1+a_{22}x_2+a_{33}x_3=r_3\\
\end{array}
}
\right.\\
a_{22}x_2=b_2\\
a_{31}x_1+a_{32}x_2+a_{33}x_3+a_{34}x_4=b_3\\
a_{42}a_2+a_{43}x_3+a_{44}x_4+a_{45}x_5=b_4
\left\{
{
\begin{array}{l}
a_{44}z_4+a_{45}z_5=r_4\\
a_{52}z_2+a_{53}z_3+a_{54}z_4+a_{55}z_5=r_5\\
\end{array}
}
\right.\\
a_{52}x_2+a_{53}x_3+a_{54}x_4+a_{55}x_5=b_5\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `cases` and `\smash`, with no `array`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\qquad\textbf{b)}\begin{cases}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_1+a_{13}x_3+a_{14}x_{4}=b_1 & \\
a_{22}x_2=b_2 &\smash{\begin{cases}a_{11}z_1+a_{12}z_2+a_{13}z_3=r_1\\
    a_{22}z_2=r_2\\
    a_{31}x_1+a_{22}x_2+a_{33}x_3=r_3 \end{cases}}\\
a_{31}x_1+a_{32}x_2+a_{33}x_3+a_{34}x_4=b_3 & \\
a_{42}a_2+a_{43}x_3+a_{44}x_4+a_{45}x_5=b_4 & \\
a_{52}x_2+a_{53}x_3+a_{54}x_4+a_{55}x_5=b_5 & \raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{$\smash{\begin{cases}a_{44}z_4+a_{45}z_5=r_4\\
a_{52}z_2+a_{53}z_3+a_{54}z_4+a_{55}z_5=r_5\end{cases}}$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note that the second set of cases is slightly low to avoid the lower braces hitting the upper ones. If you want you can set the `\raisebox` to `.632\normalbaselineskip` to align the equations. But then you may want to lower the second set by adding additional space after the `b_3`. I like the way this looks:

```
a_{31}x_1+a_{32}x_2+a_{33}x_3+a_{34}x_4=b_3 & \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
```

---

But I think a better way would be to use `aligned`.

[image]

```
\begin{equation*}
\textbf{b)}\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_1+a_{13}x_3+a_{14}x_{4}&=b_1\\
a_{22}x_2&=b_2\\
a_{31}x_1+a_{32}x_2+a_{33}x_3+a_{34}x_4&=b_3\\
a_{42}a_2+a_{43}x_3+a_{44}x_4+a_{45}x_5&=b_4\\
a_{52}x_2+a_{53}x_3+a_{54}x_4+a_{55}x_5&=b_5\\
\end{aligned}
\right.\hspace{-1em}
\begin{tabular}{c}
$\left\}\hspace{-.5em}\phantom{\begin{aligned}&b_1\\&b_2\\&b_3\\ \end{aligned}}\right\{$\\
$\left\}\hspace{-.5em}\phantom{\begin{aligned}&b_1\\&b_2\\ \end{aligned}}\right\{$
\end{tabular}
\hspace{-.75em}\begin{aligned}
r_1&=a_{11}z_1+a_{12}z_2+a_{13}z_3\\
r_2&=a_{22}z_2\\
r_3&=a_{31}x_1+a_{22}x_2+a_{33}x_3\\
r_4&=a_{44}z_4+a_{45}z_5\\
r_5&=a_{52}z_2+a_{53}z_3+a_{54}z_4+a_{55}z_5
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

It requires a `\phantom` `tabular` in the middle to get the braces aligned. You can set the space between the braces by adjusting the `\hspace{-.5em}` in two places.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proposal

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_1+a_{13}x_3+a_{14}x_{4}=b_1\\
    a_{22}x_2=b_2\\
    a_{31}x_1+a_{32}x_2+a_{33}x_3+a_{34}x_4=b_3
\end{array}\begin{cases}
a_{11}z_1+a_{12}z_2+a_{13}z_3=r_1\\
a_{22}z_2=r_2\\
a_{31}x_1+a_{22}x_2+a_{33}x_3=r_3
\end{cases}\\[20pt]
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    a_{42}a_2+a_{43}x_3+a_{44}x_4+a_{45}x_5=b_4\\
    a_{52}x_2+a_{53}x_3+a_{54}x_4+a_{55}x_5=b_5
\end{array}\begin{cases}
a_{44}z_4+a_{45}z_5=r_4\\
a_{52}z_2+a_{53}z_3+a_{54}z_4+a_{55}z_5=r_5
\end{cases}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]